# Use of cc and/or bcc in google apps script MailApp.sendEmail

Tags: google-apps-script

I am running the following script in Google apps script (emailAddress is a variable pulled from a sheet):

```
MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, message,{htmlBody:message});
```

I am trying to add a cc and/or bcc string to this, but when I do so (and I using the correct format) I am getting a consistent error that there are too many strings when I do so.

Is MailApp.sendEmail limited to only four strings? Is my use of the {htmlBody:message} the problem? I was able to partially achieve what I am trying to do by eliminating this, but my goal is to send an html email out and copy that email to an internal address so all my staff can see the sent email, rather than only the sender.

Another issue is that I do not want the following

```
var emailSent = row[5];
if (emailSent != "EMAIL_SENT")
```

to operate on the cc'd and/or bcc'd email or my source sheet will include two EMAIL_SENT entries for every email.

Is there a solution?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Please try this:

```
MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, message, {
  htmlBody: message,
  cc: 'internal1@email.com',
  bcc: 'internal2@email.com'
});
```

There are other parameters also available check here : https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/mail/mail-app#sendemailrecipient-subject-body-options

Comment: Leave the third parameter for "body" as an empty string if using `htmlBody`  in the advanced parameters.  Otherwise, you have `message` in the settings twice.

Comment: Umair's solution worked, for purposes of sending the email; what about for eliminating the

    var emailSent = row[5];
    if (emailSent != "EMAIL_SENT")

operation on the cc'd and/or bcc'd email so I don't get EMAIL_SENT returned to my spreadsheet for the cc'd/bcc'd email?

Comment: Kindly post that as a separate question and please elaborate a little more, provide relevant code snippet, maybe sheet link/snapshot of the relevant data?

Comment: Done: Google Apps Script: sendEmail from sheet using cc and/or bcc, and avoid return of EMAIL_SENT to sheet

Answer (score 3):

```js
function myFunction(){

  
  // html email
  var htmlEmailBody = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('html-template-name');

  // email title
  var subject = "your title here..";
  
  // this must be set or .sendEmail will not work. You can insert your own email address to get a copy of the email or just let it blank. Alternative you can delete bcc and just the emailAddress value to send 1 email only.
  var emailAddress = "";
  
  // same like emailAddress this must be set aswell. You can just keep it blank and use htmlBody for your html email. Alternative delete htmlBody and use normalBody for plain text email instead.
  var normalBody = "";
 

MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, normalBody, {
  htmlBody: htmlEmailBody.evaluate().getContent(),
  bcc: 'sample1@gmail.com,sample2@web.de'
});

    

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following syntax with an HTML template.

```
   /**
   * Send email with CC
   * @param {string} email - to email address
   * @param {string} cc_email - cc email address
   * @param {string} email_subject - subject of the email
   * @param {string} from_name - email will appear to be from this name
   * @param {string} template_name - name of HTML template
   */
    function sendEmail(email, cc_email, email_subject, from_name, template_name) {
        var templ = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile(template_name);
        var message = templ.evaluate().getContent();
        MailApp.sendEmail({
          to: email,
          cc: cc_email,
          subject: email_subject,
          htmlBody: message,
          name: from_name
        });
    }
```

Here is the official documentation of MailApp.sendEmail with advanced options:
https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/mail/mail-app#sendEmail(String,String,String,Object)