# Add Bcc address from Gmail Addon

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail-addons

I'm developing a new Gmail Add-on, which extends Compose user interface.
After user do some interactions with add-on (cards) I need to add Bcc address to email, actually this is draft.

as I see from documentation I can change only body of email, add images, text etc. But how to change Bcc/Subject etc. - not clear.

Is it possible to add Bcc address if my add-on for extending compose user interface?

Thanks

Comment: Possible Duplicate of [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49558662/use-of-cc-and-or-bcc-in-google-apps-script-mailapp-sendemail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49558662/use-of-cc-and-or-bcc-in-google-apps-script-mailapp-sendemail)

Comment: Not really, I need to change active compose draft, but as I see I can change only content: `var response = CardService.newUpdateDraftActionResponseBuilder()
          .setUpdateDraftBodyAction(CardService.newUpdateDraftBodyAction().addUpdateContent(...` @JohnThompson

Comment: @VladDeatlov Did you end up finding a solution?